# Clearquest sync issue

Tags: clearquest

Below issue encountered while syncing clearquest replica.
I am not sure why multiutil is searching for 'CQMS.CRD.REPL2_SH'.

Is there any way to find out the history of clearquest connection or the site or clearquest replica. So that I can find out if the connection was renamed or 
removed by other admin.

In maintenance tool, I find only one connection CQMS.ASIA.REPL_SH

```
C:\Windows\system32>multiutil syncreplica  -import  -clan ASIA -user admin -pass xxxxxxx -fam MASTR -site REPL_SH
  C:\Rational\ClearCase\var\shipping\ms_ship\incoming\sync_REPL_BE_17-01-16_03-12-21.xml
Multiutil: CRMMD1746E Connection name 'CQMS.CRD.REPL2_SH' does not exist.
The packlet being imported was epoch number 2001 from database 'MASTR',
replica 'REPL2_SH' (UUID = 1X496B3B-X8CD-4VVF-C7CA-WCA6A8TF98Z0).
```

Multiutil: Packet C:\Rational\ClearCase\var\shipping\ms_ship\incoming\sync_REPL_BE_17-01-16_03-12-21.xml not processed...

C:\Windows\system32>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with ClearQuest Multisite (none of my clients have ever bothered with it, using CQWeb instead), but the first thing I'd try is creating a new connection called CQMS.CRD.REPL2_SH, make it identical to your existing connection, and try the import again.

Comment: I renamed the connection to CQMS.CRD.REPL2_SH and it worked. I think some other admin might have renamed it accidentally.

Comment: You'd have different profiles at each site because they're using different backend database servers - the different names could be to easily identify which server it connects to.

Answer (score 0):

ClearQuest will rename a dbset when you activate multisite on it.

The name becomes
CQMS..

Do not rename this or you risk breaking multisite synchronization.